# protobuf: RepeatedField unique elements

Tags: c++, c, protocol-buffers

I want to have in a google protocol buffer `repeated field` only unique elements. In other words, need to use it as a `std::set` instead of `std::vector`.

Any idea which is the simplest and most efficient way to do that?

**EDIT**: I wouldn't want to use any iterators to loop through all the elements if possible.

Comment: Google protobufs don't support that granular of detail in their interfaces.  You could modify the source code, but that seems like a giant waste of time.  Iterating through all of the elements and adding them to a set is probably the best solution.

Comment: ...k, thnks, that confirm my findings :)

Comment: Are you constrained by google protobufs, or are you allowed to use a different toolkit for your code?

Comment: While gpb are very constrained and cannot create a precise api, I think there is a strength in this simplicity.  It is very easy to look at a protobuf definition in clear text and understand exactly what it's doing.  Try doing that with a complicated xml schema; you'll be lost for days!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as the comments from the question stated, there isn't any way of doing this without using iterators. 
However, maybe someone else is interested in this, here is the function i coded to achieve this. This will take as parameters a `RepeatedPtrField< T >*`(the list) and a `std::string`(key of the new object that we intend to add to the list) and will return the element that matches the id, or `NULL` if there isn't any entry with this key in the `RepeatedField` list.

This way, you can easy keep a list of unique elements directly in a `RepeatedField` without using any other `std` structure:

```
template <class T>
T* repeatedFieldLookup( google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField< T >* repeatedPtrField, std::string id)
{
   google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedPtrOverPtrsIterator<T> it = repeatedPtrField->pointer_begin();
   for ( ; it != repeatedPtrField->pointer_end() ; ++it )
   {
      CommonFields * commonMessage = (CommonFields*) (*it)->GetReflection()->
     MutableMessage ((*it), (*it)->GetDescriptor()->FindFieldByName ("common"));
      if(commonMessage->id() == id)
      {
     return *it;
      }
   }
   return NULL;
}
```

**NOTE**: in the example above, the proto message will ALWAYS have a field called `common`(which in my case is also a proto message). You can replace that by anything that you want to make the comparison from your proto messages.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where I had this class:

```
class Description : public ::google::protobuf::Message {
  // ...
  inline void add_field(const ::std::string& value);
  inline const ::google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField< ::std::string>& field() const;
  // ...
};
```

I used `std::find` to only add a value if it didn't exist in the list:

```
#include <algorithm>

void addField(Description& description, const std::string& value) {
    const auto& fields = description.field();
    if (std::find(fields.begin(), fields.end(), value) == fields.end()) {
        description.add_field(value);
    }
}
```